# uninitialized constant Model1::Model2::Model3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting `uninitialized constant Project::Forum::Topic` at

```
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:46:in `discussions'
```

I have code below and I am converting from `rails 2.3.x` to `rails 3.2.11`, I am thinking something wrong in `routes` setting.

Any Idea How can I fix?

**models**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Relations under project model
      has_many :features, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :forums, :class_name=>'Forum::Forum'
      has_many :topics, :class_name=>'Forum::Topic', :through=>:forums
class Forum::Forum < Feature
  # Relations under forum model
  has_many :topics, :class_name => 'Forum::Topic', :dependent => :destroy

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relations under feature model
  belongs_to :project

class Forum::Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Relations under topic model
   belongs_to :forum, :foreign_key => :forum_id, :class_name => 'Forum::Forum', :include => :project
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def discussions
  @project ||= Project.find_by_name 'help'
  @forums = @project.forums
  @topics = @project.topics.recent # HERE I AM GETTING ERRORS
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
scope :home, :controller => "home", :activity => 'read' do
 get :discussions, :path => '/forums', :service_type => 'public'
 get :forums, :action => "discussions"
end
```

**errors**

```
uninitialized constant Project::Forum::Topic
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:46:in `discussions'
```

Comment: Could you please include which files these classes are defined within? I noticed you're also missing the `class` call from before the class names. Is that really how the code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answerd via rails forum, here again,

In your project model class, change below way

OLD: `has_many :topics, :class_name=>'Forum::Topic', :through=>:forums`

NEW: `has_many :topics, :class_name=>'::Forum::Topic', :through=>:forums`

it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you autoload that class (that is, you do not `require` its source file), the cause could be a bug of Ruby `autoload` having troubles to autoload constants nested 3 or more times.

At the moment I can't find my source of this info on the internet; however, I rembember that it should be resolved with Ruby 2.0, so you can fix it removing the files you need from `autoload`, adding a `require 'project/forum/topic'` where you need, or upgrading to Ruby 2.0.

Comment: I didn't catch you, I am using Rails 3.2.x

Comment: Rails doesn't belongs to the problem I had, it was a Ruby issue; how did you call the files which define `Project`, `Forum` and `Topic`? which is the folder structure where they are?